# Proxy settings in requests library Python

Tags: python, python-requests, firewall

I have a Python script used to connect to Parse.com (remote server) and upload a file. The script runs off a server that sits behind a corporate firewall.

```
import env
import json
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPProxyAuth

def uploadFile(fileFullPath):
    print "Attempting to upload file: " + fileFullPath

    proxies = {
        "http": "http://10.128.198.14",
        "https": "http://10.128.198.14"
    }

    auth = HTTPProxyAuth('MyDomain\MyUsername', 'MyPassord')

    headers = {
        "X-Parse-Application-Id": env.X_Parse_APP_ID,
        "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": env.X_Parse_REST_API_Key,
        "Content-Type": "application/pdf"
    }   

    f = open(fileFullPath, 'r')
    files = {'file': f}
    r = requests.post(env.PARSE_HOSTNAME + env.PARSE_FILES_ENDPOINT + "/" + env.PARSE_FILE_NAME, files=files, headers=headers, timeout=10, verify=False, proxies=proxies)
    print r.text
```

When I used this module from the command prompt, I got the following message:

```
ConnectionError thrown. Details:  Cannot connect to proxy. Socket error: Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required.
```

I am pretty sure the username and password are both correct.

Any solution? Thanks!

Comment: You didn't provide the `auth` parameter to the `requests.post()` method

Comment: I added "auth" to requests.post() but it still failed due to the same error...

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the `407` error is that the proxy itself needs to be authenticated. So for your `proxies` dict, do the following:

```
proxies = {
    "http": "http://user:pass@10.128.198.14",
    "https": "http://user:pass@10.128.198.14"
}
```

Fill in the `user` and `pass` variables in the `proxies` urls. [Here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#proxies) is a link to the relevant requests documentation on how to build proxy objects and have them authenticated.

Comment: I did try this, but still the same error. Weirdly, the IE Options -> LAN has the same proxy settings and IE works well.

Comment: It's very weird. When I got the proxy sever set up from IE Options -> LAN, it threw this 407 error. While I ticked proxy server off and enabled "Automatically detect settings" it sometime worked!